# how i can retrieve Minimum Amount in magento 2 using REST API?

Tags: api, rest-api

Dears

I am using Magento ver. 2.2.7 as backend for my app,

i want to get "Minimum Amount" for orders when my users review them bascket.

So i am looking for API to retrieve value of  "Minimum Amount".

thank you for your help